# JavaFX manually trigger FocusLost event for testing Slider listener

Tags: java, javafx, junit

I have a Slider on my Pane with listener on focus property to do some logic only when value change is finished and focus is lost:

```
public class MyPane extends GridPane {
    private Slider mySlider;
    public MyPane () {
        this.mySlider= new Slider(...);
        this.mySlider.focusedProperty().addListener(e -> {
            if (!mySlider.isFocused()) {
                doSmth();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It works well but I don't see how to cover this logic with unit tests.

Since the focusProperty is ReadOnly I don't see how to manually change it's value to trigger the listener in unit tests:

```
@Test
    public void settingsPaneHasRAMSlider() {
        List<Node> sliderList = myPane.getChildren().filtered(node -> node.getClass().equals(Slider.class));
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, sliderList.size());

        Slider slider = (Slider) sliderList.get(0);

        slider.fireEvent(/* FOCUS AND UNFOCUSSED EVENT? */);

        Mockito.verify(myMock).doSmth();
    }
```

I tried with mouse click and manually change the slider value in test code, but it doesn't trigger the InvalidationListener I added to the focusProperty of my slider. Also I tried with `slider.requestFocus();` and `myPane.requestFocus()` later but since it's a unit test, there's no Stage/Scene and therefore requestFocus doesn't do anything.

Do you know how to emulate the focus changed?

Comment: As far as I know, node-focus has no meaning in JavaFX without the context of a `Scene`. Have you considered adding your slider to a `Scene` for the test?

Comment: you mean to create some TestScene in test code and add a myPane.getSlider() to a Scene directly?

Comment: What are you really trying to test here? If you’re testing whether your `doSmth()` method works, just invoke it. If you’re testing whether your listener gets invoked when the focus changes, then that seems to be a test of the FX library code, which surely is not the job of your unit test.

Comment: @JamesD, I'm testing that this listener is present and it does call `doSmth()` (with Mockito, nevermind). But there's no way to fetch all listeners using the javaFX API, that's why i.e. for buttons we call fireEvent(MouseClickedEvent) in unit tests to verify .onMouseClick(...) does some specific login. Same idea for Slider but here we have no event listener but focusListener and it's hard to emulate in unit tests

Answer (score 0):

Seems there's no other way except to use the reflection here. Even when add a Slider to a Scene created in test method, and invoke `requestFocus()` later it indeed set slider as a focusOwner but doesn't trigger a focusProperty listener.

So I reached what I wanted with next code:

```
@Test
    public void myTest() throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        List<Node> sliderList = myPane.getChildren().filtered(node -> node.getClass().equals(Slider.class));
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, sliderList.size());

        Slider slider = (Slider) sliderList.get(0);

        Method m = Node.class.getDeclaredMethod("setFocused", boolean.class);
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(slider, true);

        double newXmxValue = 2 * slider.getValue(); //double the default value !=0
        slider.setValue(newXmxValue);

        m.invoke(slider, false);

        Mockito.verify(controllerMock).doSmth();
    }
```